# How would I push content without overlapping using sidebar menu?

Tags: image, resize, toggle, sidebar

I have tried pushing my sites content using sidebar menu that toggles like the following site:

http://watchmore.co/

Although mine does not seem to be resizing the content/images, what should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have looked over the site and found that he is using class='img-responsive' on all the images. And also he is using bootstrap grid system that helps you to resize your contents for different screen sizes. You need to integrate your project with bootstrap css from http://getbootstrap.com